# What is the meaning of the story of demon doubles?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, marriage, sheidim-demons, myths

Every man and woman that is born has a demonic double also born in the world of hell ruled by Samael, the Evil One. The world of hell is in all respects identical to the world of humanity. If you were to look at your double, it would be as if you were staring at your own eyes in a mirror. Each person is appointed a soulmate by angels of heaven, and if the hands of fate are fortunate, the couple meet and form a happy union.

But woe to the person who is alone on the fourth night of the week, or on the Sabbath, because sons of Samael kidnap the person and force them to marry not their partner fated by heaven, but their demonic double.

https://www.matthewkressel.net/2015/09/19/36-days-of-judaic-myth-day-12-your-demonic-double/

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please can you find a better source for this story as this post doesn't provide any sources. There are similar sounding aggadic parables, and none of them are meant to be taken literally (unless we have a tradition that says otherwise).  Derech Hashem part 3:1-6 explains the Jewish belief of "demons".

Comment: It says in the article "The belief in the soulmate comes from the Talmud, B. Sota 2a"

Comment: Indeed, but this Talmud passage does not discuss anything to do with demons.

Comment: I'm gonna assume this is part of esoteric mysticism instead of the popular mainstream beliefs

Comment: You may do so, but I would recommend not assuming anything until we find the source. It sounds more aggadic than kabbalistic to my mildly experienced ears. In fact, my mildly experienced ears are also doubting it entirely.